# Force a play button on jwplayer mobile while seeking

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

So I found this great code that lets me add #t=[seconds] to the end of my url which allows the viewer to jump to that specific time. Here is the code:

```
jwplayer().onReady(function() {
    if(window.location.hash) {
        var offset = window.location.hash.substr(3);
        jwplayer().seek(offset);
    }
});
```

This works beautifully on the desktop but not on mobile. The issue there is not much the seeking (it actually seeks perfectly fine once you start the video), but rather the user has no ides where to click. All that is shown is the video image. Now if you tap on that, then a play button will appear, but I was wondering if there was a way to force a play button anyways. I created a class that superimposed a play button on top of the image with the following code:

```
var d = document.getElementById("jwplayer");
d.className = d.className + " otherclass";
```

This adds the play button, but the video no longer jumps to the right time. Any ideas how I can either add a play button or force the controls to appear on mobile devices when the #t= is used?

Comment: This is really because on mobile you can't autostart in html5 <video> natively, so seeking as soon as a player loads, causing the player to try to play back. This is something that should be fixed in 6.12 though, as it will show a play icon now even if onReady() is used with play() or seek()